# How to execute Stored Procedure of MS SQL server through Amazon Lambda?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2

I have one stored procedure which is too long and occurs more than a thousand times with different variables. Normal execution on Server takes around 3-4 hours to complete. That is why I want to execute that SP in parallel on the elastic server to speed up the processing.

First execution of SP is independent from second one. So, it is possible to run single SP on thousand thread with different variables. Is there any solution to execute SP in parallel or use Amazon lambda to run it through Node.js API services? Are there any other ways I can execute it in faster way except using elastic server?

Comment: Please clarify the question. Do you mean your SP takes too long to run? Does each execution of this SP take 3-4 hours, or is the SP called over a thousand times in some other process, and that other process (with all 1000 SP calls) takes 3-4 hours? What triggers the outer process to run? Are you sure the SP is written such that having multiple copies of it run at once won't cause problems (for instance, does it store and process data temporarily in a standard table, so multiple running copies would see data from the other copies)?

Comment: Actually the SP is too long. It contains for loop with more that thousand iterations. Each iteration is quite large and computationally complex. So this SP takes 3-4 hours to complete execution.